# What does しようと mean here

Tags: grammar

> あなたがなにを見つけようと、それは途方もなく危険なものにきまっている。大勢の人が私達を殺そうとしてるんだから

Usually theres a shiyou after the volitonal form if it's used like that, but why not here, what does it mean ? Because the to ends a clause it seems like a condition marker, but wouldn't it be みつけると in that case?

Answer (score 4):

> 「Verb in Volitional Form + **と or が**」

is a common expression meaning:

> "even if", "no matter what/how", etc.

Learn this construct and you will be able to say so many things.

> 「あなたがなにを見{み}つけよう**と**、それは途方{とほう}もなく危険{きけん}なものにきまっている。」

thus means:

> "**No matter what you find**, it would have to be an incredibly dangerous thing."

***IMPORTANT: Note that this is a completely different construct from***:

> 「Verb A in Continuative Form + ようと + Verb B」

Which means:

> "(Verb B) in an attempt to (Verb A)"

Thus, for instance:

> 「おいしいラーメン屋{や}を見{み}つけよう**と**、シカゴ中歩{じゅうある}き回{まわ}った。」

means:

> "I wandered all over Chicago in an attempt to find a great ramen shop."

Finally, please note that neither of the two usages of 「と」 discussed above denotes the 'plain conditional'.  The plain conditional 「と」 works as below:

> 「スミスを探{さが}していた。モールで見{み}つけたが、私{わたし}を見{み}る**と**スミスは逃{に}げていった。」
>
> "I was looking for Smith.  I found him at the mall, but **when** he saw me, he ran away."

This 「と」 always attaches to the dictionary form of a verb.

In other words, the three usages of 「と」 discussed above are used in conjunction with three different verb forms/conjugations - ***volitional, continuative and dictionary***, respectively.  Therefore, at least grammatically speaking, there should be no confusion as to what the usage is every time you see a 「と」.

Comment: When you use "Continuative Form", you mean 連用形 right? I'm pretty sure I was taught that something like **学校に 行こうと、戸を開けられなくてしまったんだ**  (which might not be entirely natural and please adjust if it isn't) would translate to the "attempt" meaning. Is your answer stating that it should be 行きよう rather than 行こう? Thanks.

Comment: @G-Cam 学校へいこうと 戸を開けられなかったんだ (or 開けられなく なって しまった) is incomplete and it needs （学校へいこうと）したら（戸を）because going to school can't be a manner that describes how you fails to open the door. (What you wanted is actually 開けられないでしまった but it's still off here. なくてしまった is simply ungrammatical.)